# C# regex split for A non-zero digit followed by an arbitrary number of zero

Tags: c#, regex

I have a number as a string "10009003" i would like to split it using regex to always get the first non-zero digit and include all trailing zeroes. Then get the next non-zero number followed by its trailing zeroes. If a non-zero number has no trailing zeroes just grab it.

The above number string should result in array/list of length/count 3 as follows 
[0] = 1000, [1] = 900, [2] =3

I have tried this code;

```
var someNumberString = "10009003";     
string s = @"[^1-9]+";
string[] strArray = Regex.Split(someNumberString, s);
```

which only output the following but the zeros are missing;
[0] = 1 , [1] = 9 , [2] = 3

How do i get the regex to include the trailing zeros?

Thanks in advance for the help:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this lookbehind and lookahead based regex:

```
var someNumberString = "10009003";     
string s = @"(?<=[1-9]0*)(?=[1-9])";
string[] strArray = Regex.Split(someNumberString, s);

Console.Write(string.Join(" ", strArray));
//=> 1000 900 3
```

#### [Online  Demo](http://ideone.com/jt8hRx)

#### Explanation:

- `(?<=[1-9]0*)` (**Lookbehind**) - if current position preceded by a non-zero digit and 0 or more zeroes
- `(?=[1-9])` (**Lookahead**) - if current position is followed by a non-zero digit

Comment: Thanks @anubhava, this gets me the string[] array which is what i am after.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `regex.Matches` function like below.

```
String input = @"10009003";
Regex rgx = new Regex(@"[1-9]+0*");
foreach (Match m in rgx.Matches(input))
Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[0].Value);
```

`[1-9]` matches the digit which ranges from 1 to 9. `0*` matches zero or more `0`'s.

[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/rGOCER)